# jQuery - toggle & removeClass

Tags: jquery, function, toggle, removeclass

An easy one, but I can't figure it out. I have a link called #title and when you click it it toggles div called #content. This works perfectly, but in addition I'm adding "active" class to my #title link and I can't get rid of it, even with removeClass.

See code above and example link (the title should be red ONLY when the #content is expanded, not all the time).

```
$('#title').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#content').toggle();
}), function() { 
    $(this).removeClass('active');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vY3WY/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the toggleClass function along with toggle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vY3WY/1/

```
$('#title').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#content').toggle();
});
```

Or you can use a more robust version which will ensure that the class is added if the content is visible and removed otherwise.

http://jsfiddle.net/vY3WY/6/

```
$('#title').click(function() {
    $('#content').toggle();
    if ($('#content:visible').size() != 0)
    {
         $(this).addClass('active');   
    }
    else
    {
         $(this).removeClass('active');   
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the 1st version, I guess it is enough for this problem

Comment: The first example, just WOW, two lines. Awesome!

Answer (score 8):

[This version works](http://jsfiddle.net/vY3WY/2/).

```
$('#title').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    $('#content').toggle();
});
```

Check for the presence of 'active' using `hasClass` and remove it if it is there.  Add it if it is not.

Or you could use `toggleClass` to hide all that logic.

Comment: You should probably post the solution here and not just a link, for future viewers of this question if the jsfiddle perishes.  :)

Answer (score 5):

A compact and still readable (I guess) solution:

```
$('#title').click(function() {
    var isContentVisible=$('#content').toggle().is(':visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', isContentVisible);
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr84K/)

It toggles `#content` and checks whether it is visible or not afterwards. Then it toggles the class on `#title` based on the result. Could be a one-liner function also, but it would not satisfy my readability expectations then.

Comment: +1 - Nice compact solution.  I forgot about the switch on toggleClass.

Answer (score 0):

one more Solution for hide current value with other value

```
$('.my').click(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
$('.my').toggle();
```

});

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vY3WY/202/)!
This works with [reference links](http://jsfiddle.net/vY3WY/202/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the most appropriate way to do it.

`$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');`